# Como puedo hacer esta operación?

Tags: c++, matemáticas

```
   void introducir_datos (CUM FP , int &numest, float &notafinal)
{
    char resp;
    numest=0;
    float notapr, notasmc, notatest, notaprob;
    cout<<"Desea introducir datos de alumnos s/n: ";
    cin>>resp;
    while(resp=='s' && numest<N)
    {

        cout<<"Introduzca el nombre del alumno sin espacios en blanco: ";
        cin>>FP[numest].alnom;
        cout<<"Si ha subido al campus todas las tareas S/N: ";
        cin>>FP[numest].entrega;
        cout<<"Si se ha presentado a los examenes S/N: ";
        cin>>FP[numest].presentado;
        if(FP[numest].entrega=='N' || FP[numest].presentado=='N')
        {
            FP[numest].notat=0;
            FP[numest].notap=0;
            FP[numest].notapr=0;
            FP[numest].notaS=0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Nota obtenida en el test: ";
            cin>>FP[numest].notat;
            cout<<"Nota obtenida en el examen de problemas: ";
            cin>>FP[numest].notap;
            cout<<"Nota obtenida en la defensa practica: ";
            cin>>FP[numest].notapr;
            cout<<"Nota obtenida en la defenda de SMC: ";
            cin>>FP[numest].notaS;
            cout<<"Participacion en clase M/P/N (Mucho, Poco o Nada): ";
            cin>>FP[numest].part;

            FP[numest].notapr=notapr; //nota practica
            FP[numest].notaS=notasmc; //nota SMC
            FP[numest].notat=notatest; //nota test
            FP[numest].notap=notaprob; //nota problemas



            notafinal=20%(notapr)+30%(notasmc)+50%(30%(notatest)+70%(notaprob));
        }
        numest++;
        cout<<"Desea introducir mas datos s/n: ";
        cin>>resp;
    }

}
```

Quiero hacer la operación `notafinal=20%(notapr)+30%(notasmc)+50%(30%(notatest)+70%(notaprob));`
pero no se bien como hacerla y quería entender como hago, las notas son tipos float (FP[numest].nota).
Estuve estudiando estructura, y tendría que hacer la nota final que seria lo que esta igualada a la variable tipo float notafinal que tengo que pasar a otro modulo. Hay algún modo más cierto de hacer este calculo? (hay que respetar lo que dice lo que las operaciones matemáticas que ya hay claro). Saludos.

Comment: falta algo entre 30 y (notasmc)

Comment: Ya editado, gracias.

Comment: y entonces cual seria el problema???

Comment: notafinal=20%(notapr)+30%(notasmc)+50%(30%(notatest)+70%(notaprob));

Comment: como hacer este calculo en c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En muchos lenguajes de programación, el `%` hace referencia al operador `modulo` o `remainder` que nos permite calcular el [resto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resto) de una división, si lo que deseas es calcular un porcentaje, lo que debes hacer es múltiplicar la variable por el valor del porcentaje y luego dividir por 100, esto es, por ejemplo el 20% de `x` es: `(x*20)/100` o `x*0.2`.

Para tú caso en particular sería de la siguiente manera:

```
notafinal=(0.2)*(notapr)+(0.3)*(notasmc)+(0.5)*((0.3)*(notatest)+(0.7)*(notaprob));
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, eres un amigo.